# How to test exception handling when unable to trigger an Exception during testing?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, pytest

I'm working on a Django REST Framework (DRF) viewset that includes exception handling to deal with unexpected errors. The viewset has an action method that retrieves pricing information for servers from a third-party API. Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class MyViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    @action(detail=False, methods=["get"], url_path="pricing", authentication_classes=[])
    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)  # For testing purposes only
    def pricing(self, request, pk=None):
        """ List all pricing or a specific server """

        try:
            server_type = request.query_params.get("server_type")
            location = request.query_params.get("location")

            # Case 1: returns the pricing list
            if not server_type or not location:
                pricing = self.hapi.pricing()
                return Response(pricing, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

            # Case 2: returns the pricing of the provided server info
            prices = self.hapi.calculate_price(server_type, location)
            return Response(prices, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        except Exception as error:
            logger.critical(f"Error fetching server pricing: {error}", exc_info=True)
            return Response({"message": "Error fetching server pricing", "error": str(error)}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

I'm trying to test the except Exception part of the code, but I'm having trouble triggering the exception during testing. Since the code path leading to the exception is challenging to reproduce in a controlled testing environment, I'm not sure how to effectively test the exception handling logic.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
def test_prices_exception(self, mocker, client):
    """ if pricing raised any exception """
    exception_error = "mock error"
    mocker.patch("core.views.datacenter.abc.abcVPS.pricing",
                 side_effect=Exception(exception_error))
    mock_logger = mocker.patch(
        "core.views.datacenter.abc.logger")

    url = SERVER_PRICE_URL

    response = client.get(url)

    assert "message" in response.data
    assert "error" in response.data
    assert mock_logger.critical.wrap_assert_called_once_with(
        f"Error fetching server pricing: {exception_error}")
    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

here I'm mocking the method itself (pricing) which will lead to an error. and I also cant go any further to mock something inside the 'pricing' method. or maybe I just don't know how to...
is it even necessary to test something like this?

- How can I test the except Exception part of the code when it's difficult to raise an Exception during testing?
- Do you have any tips or tricks for simulating the conditions that would lead to the exception being raised in a controlled testing environment?
- Are there any alternative approaches or best practices for testing exception handling in DRF action methods when it's not feasible to trigger the exception during testing?

Any advice or insights on testing exception handling would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: if you want to force crash, can just set variable inside try like a = no_existing_variable or raise Exception("test exception")

Comment: That's actually a good way to do it but I'm trying to find a cleaner way

Answer (score 1):

Most naive solution: you could split this up into two methods:

```py
def pricing(self, request, pk=None):
    """ List all pricing or a specific server """
    try:
        self._pricing(request, pk)
    except Exception as error:
        logger.critical(f"Error fetching server pricing: {error}", exc_info=True)
        return Response({"message": "Error fetching server pricing", "error": str(error)}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

def _pricing(self, request, pk):
    server_type = request.query_params.get("server_type")
    location = request.query_params.get("location")

    # Case 1: returns the pricing list
    if not server_type or not location:
        pricing = self.hapi.pricing()
        return Response(pricing, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    # Case 2: returns the pricing of the provided server info
    prices = self.hapi.calculate_price(server_type, location)
    return Response(prices, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

To then test the exception handling, you only need to mock the `_pricing` method with a side effect.

```py
def test():
    with mock.patch("path.to._pricing", new=Mock(side_effect=Exception(exception_error))):
        response = client.get(url)
        ...
```